# mongoose $match wont return document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, match

I use two ways to retrieve documents from my collection, the first one:

```
db.comments.find({"nid" : "req.body.data"});
```

returns many doc like:

```
{
    "nid" : 20404,
    "_id" : ObjectId("5638ba331294943d3d0a092b"),
    "uid" : 1937,
    "posted" : ISODate("2015-11-03T13:44:19.811Z"),
    "text" : "txt",
    "title" : "Test nid 2",
    "stars" : 3,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

,
And for another query I need to use `aggregate` and the query:

```
var pipleline = [
            {$match: {nid:req.body.data}}

        ];
        Comments.aggregate(pipleline, function(err, rank){
                if(err) {
                    res.send("Error", String(err));
                }
                res.send(rank);
            });
```

Returns `[]` - empty array.
Any ideas?

Comment: What's the value of `req.body.data`?

Comment: Number, is it related to parsing?

Comment: when retrieving `req.body.data` you need to make you have a value there. Use `console.log` to make sure there is an actual `nid` being saved.

Comment: No, that is not the problem, the log prints the same thing.

Comment: so if you hard code the value, you still get an empty array?

Comment: Yes, same goes for the mongo console. I believe it is a parsing problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in function chaining mongoose provides. Aside from match, it also has sort, project, group, and few others I don't know off the top of my head. More info [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-match)

```
        Comments.aggregate().match({nid:req.body.data})
        .exec(function(err,rank){
            if(err) {
                res.send("Error", String(err));
            }
            res.send(rank);
        });
```